# Removing fill from text embedded in image

Tags: text, paint.net

I have a PNG file with text scattered over the image. I want to remove the dark fill in the letters leaving just an outline for use in a laser printer.

What's the best way to go about achieving this (preferably using Paint.NET)? Example image shown below -

[image]

Comment: There is no easy answer here. With raster images such as PNG, you need to use a tool to erase anything you do not want. There is no magic button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this solution may help if you have OSX+Pixelmator. If not, probably it will help you by analogy.

This is part of your image:

[image]

I click on Paint Selection Tool -

[image]

And click on the white of the image getting this selection areas -

[image]

Now, I apply stroke to the selection -

[image]

with any options I want -

[image]

The final result with background layer hidden (I can just delete it):

[image]

I can add any background I want of course...

Comment: That is a very cool example and exactly what I am looking for. Can't find a plugin similar to the Stroke functionality you use in Paint.NET at the moment but will keep looking.